# Spring @RequestBody and default values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring creates a new Object of the correct type when receiving the details as an @ResponseBody parameter (e.g. `public void createUser(@RequestBody User user)`. I'm sending the data to the server as JSON, and Spring creates the new user object as specified.

My question is, is there anyway to get Spring to ignore the auto-generated fields I have (like createDate, etc). So, if I, for example, pass in `{"username":"sam"}` and nothing else, I'd like a user object that only has the username field populated, and none of the other fields (even if that is invalid).

The reason I am asking this is because my User inherits some default autogenerated attributes from another object which I cannot touch, and I need to have an object that has all fields null except for the fields that come in from the request. **update:** I can then merge the newly created object with the object in the JpaRepository (ignoring the nulls).

Thank you  :-)

Comment: You may have to override the getters of those fields and add the annotation `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Looks on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921736/parsing-json-into-java-objects-in-spring-mvc

Comment: It sounds like the other fields such as createDate are set upon instantiation? There is no way around this. The only way I can think around this would be to set all of the values to Null in the default constructor of your User object.

Comment: Thanks ninn: I think you are right. I will have to settle on removing all default values and have a pseudo constructor of some kind that is called before a new object is initially persisted to the database. Please list your answer so I can accept it :)
..
Thanks Arun: If I JsonIgnore the fields, they will not be updatable at all. I would like them to update only if JSON data comes in for that particular field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It do have the way to do that. For example: `@initBinder or convertService`, but it will be more complex, and I also don't know exact implementation to do that code. While the easiest way is that you create a new class, may be called: `TmpUser` and just has 1 field: userName, you use this class to accept the request data, and copy the data to User, then it can meet you requirement. You can use `Spring utils. BeanUtils.copyProperties()` to do the copy.

Comment: Thanks Lakshmi. The data coming in could have multiple fields or one of many, not just username. I wouldn't want to copy null values over.
Also, any idea on how to do a deep copy of the objects with BeanUtils?

Comment: If you use BeanUtils.copyProperties(User,TmpUser); and it will copy the field valus in TmpUser to User, and because some fields in User is not included in TmpUser, so after the copy that those part of field values will be kept as default which will be null.

Answer (score 0):

If you return a User object, all fields are included automaticly by default, you cann't change it. but you can just return a HashMap with uername populated.

```
@ResponseBody public Map createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    ...
    Map userCreated = new HashMap();
    userCreated.put("username", user.getUsername());
    return userCreated;
}
```

In other way, you can define and create a new UserForm object to do what you expect to return as below.

```
public class UserForm{

    private String username;

    public UserForm(User user){
        this.username = user.getUsername();
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;    
    }
}

@ResponseBody public UserForm createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    ...

    return new UserForm( user );
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you Henry. If I implement a Map like you suggest in the first example, what would be the best way to put the values from the map into an existing User object in the database, only updating the fields that came in?