# Read JSON into Model object or Data Transfer Object (DTO)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and am having trouble figuring out the right way to read JSON data sent from a JavaScript client into Java objects.

- Use Jackson to map the JSON directly into my Model classes. These classes are annotated with @Entity and are directly used by hibernate. Is there any reason not to have Jackson read the JSON directly into these classes?

JSON -> Model

- Create intermediate *mapper* classes between my Models and my JSON. Then in the controller, the mapper objects are used to create a Model object. I wouldn't have thought to do this, but a coworker had done it this way and now I am wondering if this is a recommended way to do it.

JSON -> Mapper Classes -> Model

Is there a best practice when it comes to mapping incoming JSON?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing json into java objects in spring-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921736/parsing-json-into-java-objects-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's better to have a custom DTO for this case, both because you'll want fine-grained access control and because decoupling allows you to evolve the two representations separately as makes sense (maybe what looks like a single HTTP resource is really the result of a join). I would go so far as to say that Spring Data REST is an antipattern.

Look at Spring HATEOAS for a framework that makes resource representation and mapping much easier.